# Get the value of selected option and comparing the value outside select tag to get more data for that value

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and recently I made a select tag with `ng-repeat`. I have a JSON API `propertyDetails` in which I have details of some properties.

I am able to get the names of all the properties in the select tag option through `ng-repeat` with the `propertyID` from the API being set as the value of the option. In the API, I have a parameter propertyType.

What I am trying to achieve now is when I select a propertyName from the select options, the propertyType is displayed in a `<p>` tag according to the selected property from the select tag.

```html
<select ng-if="user.role=='2'" id="propertyDropdown" ng-model="propertyDetails.model">
  <option ng-repeat="prop in propertyDetails" value={{ prop.id }}>{{ prop.name }}</option>
</select>
<p>{{ here I want the property type according to the selected property }} </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple just write a call ng-change on your select and then pass the index value to change the function or you can set proptype value in ng-change directly to

```
<select ng-if="user.role=='2'" ng-model="prop_id" id="propertyDropdown">
  <option ng-repeat="prop in propertyDetails" value={{ prop.id }} ng-change="changed(prop)">{{ prop.name }}</option>
</select>
<p>{{ propType }} </p>
```

In controller:

```
function changed(prop){
  $scope.propType = prop.propertyType
}
```

Comment: But @Rohan please go through stack overflow question once before asking you will not get exact answers but try to modify as per your need it will be good practice.

Comment: I should, yeah! Thanks for the advice :D Will surely work more!